# If there is XHR request, how to wait for all XHR requests to finish. If not, do not wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ui-automation, playwright

I wrote a helper method that waits for all XHR requests to be completed. But in some places where I use this method, there is no XHR request. For this, I need to add a loop into helper method. If there is XHR request, wait for all XHR requests to finish, if not, do not wait. How can I edit this in the method below? Do you think this method is correct? I want to wait for all XHR requests to be completed and I think I did it right. If you have an edit suggestion, I would like to learn it too. But the main problem is if there is no XHR request, I don't want to wait. If there is, I want to wait.

```
import {Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class InflightRequests {
    page: Page;
    requests: Set<unknown>;
  constructor(page:Page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.requests = new Set();
    this._onStarted = this._onStarted.bind(this);
    this._onFinished = this._onFinished.bind(this);
    this.page.on('request', this._onStarted);
    this.page.on('requestfinished', this._onFinished);
    this.page.on('requestfailed', this._onFinished);
  }

  _onStarted(request:any) { this.requests.add(request); }
  _onFinished(request:any) { this.requests.delete(request); }
 
  inflightRequests() { return Array.from(this.requests); }  

  dispose() {
    this.page.removeListener('request', this._onStarted);
    this.page.removeListener('requestfinished', this._onFinished);
    this.page.removeListener('requestfailed', this._onFinished);
  }
}
```

**usage in the test;**

`expect.poll(() => this.tracker.inflightRequests().filter((request: any) => request.resourceType() === 'xhr').length).toBe(0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use native Playwright `waitForLoadState` method to wait for all requests to be resolved. Documentation [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-frame#frame-wait-for-load-state).

Example:

```
await page.click('button');
await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle'); // wait until there are no network connections for at least 500 ms.
```